# gFortran and OpenACC support

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, openacc

According to the [gFortran docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenACC.html) in order to enable OpenACC support it is necessary to use the `-fopenacc` switch. However, this does not seem to work.

```
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fopenacc’
```

gFortran version is `GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)`.

What is the correct way to compile Fortran code with OpenACC support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is WAY too old. The currently supported versions of GCC are 7, 8 and 9.
The version specific manuals are available at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gfortran/OpenACC.html#OpenACC Change the version number in the address to see other versions.

The option appears to be added in version 5 but the support in more recent versions is likely to be much better.